# Scraping web data with select/option using request_html and BeautifulSoup in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html, select-options

I am new to data scraping, but I don't ask this question carelessly without digging around for a suitable answer.

I want to download the table from this page: https://www.portodemanaus.com.br/?pagina=nivel-do-rio-negro-hoje.

As you can see from the following screenshot, there are a couple of select/option on the top of the table. The corresponding html code (on the right) shows that the second half (2) and year 2021 are selected. By re-selecting and resubmit the form, content of the table changes, but the url remains unchanged. However, the changes are reflected in the html code. See the second following screenshot, wherein options are modified into 1 and 2018.
[image]

[image]

Based on these inspections, I've put together a python script (using bs4 and requests_html) to get the initial page, modify select/option, then post them back to the url. See below for the code. However, it fails its task. The webpage doesn't response to the modification. Could anyone kindly shed some lights on it?

Thanks in advance,

Liang

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://www.portodemanaus.com.br/?pagina=nivel-do-rio-negro-hoje#"

# initialize an HTTP session
session = HTMLSession()

# Get request
res = session.get(url)

# for javascript driven website
# res.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.html.html, "html.parser")

# Get all select tags
selects = soup.find_all("select")

# Modify select tags
# Select the first half of a year
selects[0].contents[1].attrs['selected']=''
del selects[0].contents[3].attrs['selected']

# Put into a dictionary
data = {}
data[selects[0]['name']] = selects[0]
data[selects[1]['name']] = selects[1]

# Post it back to the website
res = session.post(url, data=data)

# Remake the soup after the modification
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")

# the below code is only for replacing relative URLs to absolute ones
for link in soup.find_all("link"):
    try:
        link.attrs["href"] = urljoin(url, link.attrs["href"])
    except:
        pass
for script in soup.find_all("script"):
    try:
        script.attrs["src"] = urljoin(url, script.attrs["src"])
    except:
        pass
for img in soup.find_all("img"):
    try:
        img.attrs["src"] = urljoin(url, img.attrs["src"])
    except:
        pass
for a in soup.find_all("a"):
    try:
        a.attrs["href"] = urljoin(url, a.attrs["href"])
    except:
        pass

# write the page content to a file
open("page.html", "w").write(str(soup))
```

Comment: beautifulsoup is strictly to parse html. It in no way is a means to interact with a site.

Comment: Thanks, @chitown88. Good to know this. I need to learn about the purpose of html parsing.

Comment: The purpose of html parsing is exactly that. To get information from html. Pandas’ .read_html() that I use below uses BeautifulSoup under the hood. It’s essentially parsing <table> tags in the html.

Answer (score 3):

The option can be made through a POST and passing in the `semestre` and `ano` as parameters. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

semestre = 1
ano = 2018

url = 'https://www.portodemanaus.com.br/?pagina=nivel-do-rio-negro-hoje'
payload = {
'semestre': '%s' %semestre,
'ano': '%s' %ano,
'buscar': 'Buscar'}

response = requests.post(url, params=payload)
df = pd.read_html(response.text)[7]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
              0         1   ...        11                  12
0           Dias     Julho  ...  Dezembro            Dezembro
1           Dias  Cota (m)  ...  Cota (m)  Encheu/ Vazou (cm)
2              1      2994  ...       000                 000
3              2      2991  ...       000                 000
4              3      2989  ...       000                 000
5              4      2988  ...       000                 000
6              5      2987  ...       000                 000
7              6      2985  ...       000                 000
8              7      2983  ...       000                 000
9              8      2980  ...       000                 000
10             9      2977  ...       000                 000
11            10      2975  ...       000                 000
12            11      2972  ...       000                 000
13            12      2969  ...       000                 000
14            13      2967  ...       000                 000
15            14      2965  ...       000                 000
16            15      2962  ...       000                 000
17            16      2959  ...       000                 000
18            17      2955  ...       000                 000
19            18      2951  ...       000                 000
20            19      2946  ...       000                 000
21            20      2942  ...       000                 000
22            21      2939  ...       000                 000
23            22      2935  ...       000                 000
24            23      2931  ...       000                 000
25            24      2927  ...       000                 000
26            25      2923  ...       000                 000
27            26      2918  ...       000                 000
28            27      2912  ...       000                 000
29            28      2908  ...       000                 000
30            29      2902  ...       000                 000
31            30      2896  ...       000                 000
32            31      2892  ...       000                 000
33  Estatísticas    Encheu  ...   Estável             Estável
34  Estatísticas     Vazou  ...   Estável             Estável
35  Estatísticas    Mínima  ...    Mínima                 000
36  Estatísticas     Média  ...     Média                 000
37  Estatísticas    Máxima  ...    Máxima                 000

[38 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: Great, @chitown88. Your code looks neat and works beautifully. The only typo is  that  requests.post takes **data** as the argument instead of **params**.  `response=requests.post(url,data=payload)`. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Hi, @chitown88. Mind I ask why adding **'buscar': 'Buscar'** is necessary? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Ah good catch. I think it still worked with params though. As far as the Buscar, maybe you don’t need it. But I was just basing it off what the XHR was passing in the request post.