# How to scrape data from a page with dynamic select tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to get all the data from this [page](https://transparencia.sema.ma.gov.br/pages/licencas_sigla) to a pandas DataFrame.

On the page there's a drop-down menu to select the number of results in the page, as shown in the screen below:

[image: screenshot from the page]

Here's how this select button is implemented in the HTML source code:

[image: html source code]

I want to get the data from this page with the options that show all the data (-1). So for this, I've written the following script:

```
import requests_html
import pandas as pd
import requests

def maranhao():
    session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
    response = session.post('https://transparencia.sema.ma.gov.br/pages/licencas_sigla',   data={'licencas_sigla_length':'-1'})
    response.html.render(sleep=60)
    table  = response.html.find('table', first=True)
    df  = pd.read_html(table.html)
    print(df)


maranhao()
```

Since the site content is rendered with javascript I've used request-html to get the page content and render that content.
The problem is that even passing the select tag as a parameter with the desired value I get only the 10 first results.
I've written this script based on answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021436/scraping-web-data-with-select-option-using-request-html-and-beautifulsoup-in-pyt)
but it doesn't work.
Does someone have any idea of what I could do to accomplish my desired result?